# How to manage a membership price increase for rolling memberships

Tags: civimember, renewals

Other than MembershipExtras, does anyone have other solutions for when a Memb price increase needs to be applied such that the system checks if the End Date is before or after a specific date, and hence applies correct amount for a renewal

EG both Peter and John have a membership.

Peter expires on June 28

John's expires on July 2

The fee increase is to only apply to memberships ending after June 30.

On june 25th they both go to the renewal page, at that point you are asking that the system apply different prices for them despite them having the same Membership type.

Answer (score 0):

I have an extension built that changes the price for membership 10 days before the expiry or when at the time of saving the membership type. This works for payment processors that have an update subscription amount function implemented. I am in a process of supporting it for Stripe.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this Pradeep. not sure how closely that maps with our requirements but will discuss with colleague and get back to you.